# TipTap Vue component - how to toggle wrap on node from component button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tiptap

The awesome tiptap wrapper for prosemirror comes with nice documentation but it lacks some clarification how to approach some (i think) basic scenarios when developing custom extensions.

My question is how to invoke toggleWrap on the node when in vue component's context.
I found example that uses transactions and allows for delete - but what i want is to clear the node leaving the text of node intact.

```
get view() {
        return {
        directives: {
        "click-outside": clickOutside
      },
       props: ['node', 'updateAttrs', 'view', 'selected', 'getPos'],
       data() {
        return {
            showMenu: false
        }
       },
       computed: {
        href: {
            get() {
                return this.node.attrs.href
            },
            set(href) {
                this.updateAttrs({
                    href,
                })
            },
        },
        },
        methods: {
            // deleteNode() { 
            //  let transaction = this.view.state.tr // tr - transaction
            //  let pos = this.getPos() 
            //  transaction.delete(pos, pos + this.node.nodeSize) 
            //  this.view.dispatch(transaction)
            // },
            stopLinkPropagation(){
                return null;
            },
            hideMenu(){
                this.showMenu = false
            }
        },
        template: `<div @click="showMenu = true" v-click-outside="hideMenu">
            <a class="email-button" @click.prevent="stopLinkPropagation" :href="href" v-text="node.textContent"></a>
            <input class="iframe__input" type="text" v-model="href" v-if="showMenu" />
            <button @click="clearNode">clear button wrap</button>
            </div>`,
        }
    }
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.